# Making a function suspend inside Recycler View View-Holder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines, countdowntimer, suspend

I am using a countdownTimer function inside RecyclerView View Holder. This function puts too much load on my main thead due to whih app keeps stopping. How can I make this function suspend so it can run on other thread. I have used Coroutines Scope Dispatches main but it is not working. Code is attached below.

```
  private fun timer(
        millisInFuture: Long,
        countDownInterval: Long
    ): CountDownTimer? {
        countDownTimer = (object : CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                val timeRemaining = timeString(millisUntilFinished)
                binding.btnAuctionTimer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.btnAuctionTimer.text = timeRemaining
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                binding.btnAuctionTimer.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

            }
        }).start()
        return countDownTimer
    }
```

Comment: i don't really see how this would make any difference, considering the fact that you need to update these views on the main thread, most likely. better question would probably be why you're using this _inside_ your view holder

Comment: ok, so what should be the right solution. Basically, this function gives an ANR.

Comment: What's the value you give to countDownInterval? Don't ever give it 0.